# Android: custom XML for ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I need to create a custom `ShareActionProvider` menu for my Android app, because when I specify the default one, I get only "Messaging", "Bluetooth" and "Gmail", and I only want "Facebook", "Twitter" and "Email".

How can I do this?
Do I need to specify my own layout for it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything can be found here:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/SubMenus.java